# How can I possibly add a "reduce the quantity of an item" feature in my database program?

Tags: c++, database, itemscontrol

I am making a database inventory program for my finals project. I am really new to c++, here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define ss 30
using namespace std;

struct store 
{
    char brand[30];
    char name[30];
    char pc[30];
    int x;
    float price;
}s[ss];
void AddNewItem(int &num)
{
    cout<<"\n \t\t\t   NEW DATA FOR AN ITEM\n\n\n";
    cout<<"Product Code: ";
    cin>>s[num].pc;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Company Name: ";
    cin>>s[num].brand;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Product Name: ";
    cin>>s[num].name;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Product Price ";
    cin>>s[num].price;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Quantity: ";
    cin>>s[num].x;
    num++;
    cout<<endl;
}
void ShowInventoryList(int &num)
{
    if (num==0)
    {
        cout<<"\nThere are no items in the record right now. Please add record.\n\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"\n \t\t\t LIST OF ALL ITEMS"<<endl;
        cout<<"Product Code \t Company Name \t Product Name \t Product Price \t Quantity'\t" <<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
            cout<<s[i].pc <<"\t\t"
            <<s[i].brand <<"\t\t"
            <<s[i].name <<"\t\t"
            <<s[i].price <<"\t\t"
            <<s[i].x <<"\t\t"
            <<endl
            <<endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream openFile("Inventory.txt");
    string line;
    int menu,number=0;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n====================   MENU   ====================";
        cout<<"\n                                                ";
        cout<<"\n            1. Add New Item                       ";
        cout<<"\n            2. Show Inventory List                ";
        cout<<"\n            3. Search An item From Record         ";
        cout<<"\n            4. Reduce The Quantity of An Item;    ";
        cout<<"\n            5. Save Item Stock to Text File       ";
        cout<<"\n            6. Show Item Stock from Text File     ";
        cout<<"\n            7. Exit                               ";
        cout<<"\n                                                ";
        cout<<"\n=================================================="<<endl;
        cout<<"\nEnter your choice: ";
        cin>>menu;
        switch(menu)
        {
            case 1:{AddNewItem(number);
                break;}
            case 2:{ShowInventoryList(number);
                break;}

            }
        }
    while(menu!=7);
    cout<<"\nThank you for using our program. Have a good day!";
}
```

I made the quantity of the items as int because I plan to just ask the user the quantity amount they want to reduce from the item and just subtract it from the original quantity of an item. I am stuck here and I would really appreciate the help! <3

Comment: How about `if (number > 0) --number;`?  Also, use `std::vector`, rather than a C-style array.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Thanks for the help guys, i managed to do it by using this:

```
void RemoveItemRecord(int&num)
{
    int c;
    long int pc, qnty;
    cout<<"What do you want to delete from the record?\n Please enter product code of the item:  ";
    cin>>pc;
    cout<<"Enter the amount you want to reduce from the quantity";
    cin>>qnty;
        if(num==0){
        cout<<"\nThere is no data to be deleted.\n\n";}
        else{
            for(c=0;c<num;c++){
                if(s[c].pc=pc){
                    s[c].qnty=s[c].qnty-qnty;
                }
            }
        }
}
```